# Bamboo continuous build order

Tags: continuous-integration, artifactory, bamboo, continuous-deployment

I am confused while deciding the order of Bamboo continuous build, confusion is between upload Artifacts and inetgration level(or end to end) tests

As per of my project I have set following order - 
1. Build, junit , upload artifacts (-snapshot) , integration level tests(no application required) , deploy service to server , end to end tests (require deployed application)

I have a confusion that upload artifacts (-snapshot) should be at the end i.e after end to end tests or what ever is set is the correct order.

What I thought that upload artifacts (-snapshot) should be at the end after all tests(integration and end to end tests) are passed then only snapshot should be uploaded.

second thought came to my mind that end to end tests should be done as part of  the deployed artifacts.

Any thoughts around this ?  Thanks

Comment: it depends on what is your artifact. You mentioned "snapshot".. what is the use of it.  Answer a question to yourself.. is your snapshot still valid even if end2end test or integration test fails? If yes, then you are good to do it where you are doing it. However, if otherwise, so you should do it in the end. One more suggestion, I am not sure how many tests you have in e2e, if it is just smoke test then it is fine, else do it as part of separate plan where a scheduled test is run which only does your testing. You don't want your whole application to wait for lots of e2e tests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the school of thought in continuous delivery is to avoid the ci notion of snapshot.

Have you considered at build stage to do the following

1. set version 1.0.0-buildnum;
2. run fast tests unit, integration;
3. run quality check, eg sonar;
4. tag repo with build version package; and
5. upload to artifactory/nexus with build version to a candidate-release repo;

At deploy/release stage

1. Download 1.0.0-buildnum from candidate-release;
2. Deploy package to aat;
3. Run automated functional tests (eg cucumber, jmeter)

At deploy to live:

1. Promote the artifact from cadidate-release to release repo in artifactory/nexus;
2. Deploy to live;
3. Run smoke test, deploy verification tests;

I have done this in the past by reading out the project.version from the maven pom or the npm project.json and appending the build number to the end of it. I set the version back using the build tool. E.g for maven I use something along the lines `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.0-buildnum`. When the pom is checked-in with snapshot I typically strip it off.